# BigQuery Date Conversion From String

Tags: date, google-bigquery

I've looked everywhere and can't find this answer. It's a pretty simple query, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to change the date.

I have a date coming in as a string, but it's not being picked up.  The date is being brought in as 20170601 but I need it to be in a date format to be picked up in Tableau.  I'm using Standard SQL and have tried to **PARSE_DATE("%x", date) as parsed**, **cast(date as date)**, etc. and I keep getting *Error: Failed to parse input string "20170918"* or some variation of that error.

`#standardSQL
SELECT
  visitorid,
  parse_DATE("%x", date) AS parse
FROM` `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910`

The table is within `

Please advise!!

Comment: What format does Tableau require?  Are you currently storing your date as text, or as a number?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Tableau requires some sort of DD/MM/YYYY and the absence of a / is the issue I believe.  I've tried "%f" and "%y/%m%d" but I'm still getting the same error.  In BigQuery it's being brought in as a string and storing it as such since I can't convert it to a date (not sure if that answers the second question?).

Comment: @NightOwl888 thanks! this is my first post.  I have updated the question with a simplified version of the query.

Comment: @LEllin - No problem. Although, this example does not look complete as there is no data included where it could possibly throw the error you are getting. The idea behind the MCVE is that others will be able to *run* the code and reproduce the results you are seeing.

Comment: @NightOwl888 The bigger issue here is that it's not clear why the import into Tableau is failing.  Can't write a query if you don't know what the output is supposed to be (though I took a guess below).

Comment: @NightOwl888 I have updated the query in the question.  Hopefully that fits more of the MCVE requirements!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for your help.  Tableau is not able to read the date in the string format it's being pulled in as.  I have tried to change the date in Tableau, but it's unable to read it without the / in the formatting.  I tried using the code you provided replacing '20170601' with date, however I got an error saying _missing: ^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}))_

Comment: I had an extra parenthesis, try it again.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Bingo! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try doing a regex replacement to build the date string which you require:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE('20170601', r"^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})", "\\1/\\2/\\3")
```

This would output `2017/06/01`, which perhaps is the format you require.  Actually, I don't know what format Tableau is expecting, but `YYYYMMDD` is usually the correct order for a date, because it will sort correctly as text.  You may use any replacement you want, using the above query as an example.